# How to achieve custom cropping like CamScanner in Expo Apps?

Tags: android, ios, ocr, crop, expo

Expo supports several libraries that support crop, scale, rotate and flip. But these are very basic operations. But how to achieve a custom cropping something like camscanner.

[image]

src: https://productivity-blog.vanaia.com/finding-best-android-scanner-app-auto-crop/

Can I write my own code in JS like we can do in native Android Bitmap Manipulations or are there any good libraries that can do so?

UI is not an issue, just need an API that can basically return a bitmap or image by taking four coordinates as input.

Comment: https://github.com/AndrejLukasevic/AndroidScannerDemo

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @NikunjParadva but as I mentioned, I could easily do it in JAVA Android and even in React Native using libraries. But I want to do it in Expo without ejecting.